# Use react history object to change last browser's URL

Tags: reactjs, browser, react-router

Im currently trying to use the history.push() object from:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history

Im having problem to change last's URL of browser when the browser's back button is clicked.

When I use the history.push(...) the current browser's URL changes; there is a way to avoid this? Or just using window object I can make this work?

My application is not a Single Page-Application; the code:

```
    import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
    const history = createHistory();
    const testUrl = 'http://test.com'

    history.push(testUrl);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
        history.go(testUrl);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pushState` or `replace`. pushState adds a new entry, whereas replace modifies the current.

@see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

as I can see from your module `history/createBrowserHistory`, you are using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) module, which should be fully compatible with the native implementation.

Comment: Yeah, pushState would be a solution. But I was looking to do this using the react object. Thanks for the reply x)

Comment: the react object? you dont use any react obejct there. you use a fully compatible layer from here, that does not have anything to do with react. https://www.npmjs.com/package/history

Comment: You are right. Still I can't use the push nor the replace, both changes the URL when used.